# Print a dot file from llvm pass

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I know that from your llvm pass you can call : viewCFG() or viewCFGOnly to view a graphviz representation of a function. These creates and store the .dot files somewhere in the \tmp folder under linux. Is there any way to specify in which file to save the .dot code?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from:
http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/CFGPrinter_8cpp_source.html

```
   std::string Filename = "cfg." + F.getName().str() + ".dot";
   errs() << "Writing '" << Filename << "'...";

   std::string ErrorInfo;
   raw_fd_ostream File(Filename.c_str(), ErrorInfo, sys::fs::F_Text);

   if (ErrorInfo.empty())
     WriteGraph(File, (const Function*)&F);
   else
   errs() << "  error opening file for writing!";
   errs() << "\n";
   return false;
```

Using the GraphWriter.h interface