# IR(bit code) file to Graph Representation

Tags: clang, llvm, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

Please anyone can help me out to know that how could I change the IR(bit code(.bc)) or (.ll) file to Graph representation?.. I search a lot but still having difficulties to find any idea or procedure

Comment: What terms did you search for? There's [opt -view-cfg](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#view-cfg-view-cfg-of-function) and there are also questions like [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23410835)

Comment: when i use this command an icon like a made with type application .. I am having issue with making cfg file can you please help me in this regard?